# C socket problems - random client address and port number

Tags: c, sockets, port

I have a really simple exercise to do: make a socket where when a client is connected, the server display its information (address and port number).

I wrote this:

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check arguments
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur argument\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *nom_machine = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(argv[2]);

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    // création socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // remplissage struct de l'adresse
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port); // code les octets dans l'ordre réseau
    inet_aton(nom_machine, &addr.sin_addr);

    // connnexion à 1.2.3.4:4242
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);

    // display informations
    fprintf (stderr,
            "---------\nAdresse: %s\nPort: %hd\n---------\n",
            inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr),
            ntohs(addr.sin_port));


    // envoie message
    int n = 7;
    int r = write(sock, &n, sizeof(int));
    if (r != sizeof(int)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Echec de l'envoi de n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // arrêt
    close(sock);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur argument\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    // création socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // remplissage struct de l'adresse
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port); // code les octets dans l'ordre réseau
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // création connnexion
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof addr);

    // écoute
    listen(sock, 2);

    // attend une connexion entrante
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t size;
    int lect = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &size); // (2) structure entring connection

    // display client informations
    fprintf (stderr,
            "---------\nAdresse: %s\nPort: %d\n---------\n",
            inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
            ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

    // lecture message
    int n;
    int r = read(lect, &n, sizeof(int));
    if (r <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Le serveur n'a pas recu le message\n");
                close(sock);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Affichage
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", n);

    // arrêt
    close(sock);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I test my code, the client's address and port number given by the server seems to be totally random (except that sometimes it gives the right address, but I never saw the correct port number).

Here's an example:

client console

```
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Og -o client client.c
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ ./client 127.0.0.1 3333
---------
Adresse: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3333
---------
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ ./client 127.0.0.1 3333
---------
Adresse: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3333
---------
```

server console

```
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Og -o serveur serveur.c
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ ./serveur 3333
---------
Adresse: 6.127.0.0
Port: 16578
---------
Le serveur n'a pas recu le message
thomas@thomasCoding:~/Code/2020/Reseau/TP_4$ ./serveur 3333
---------
Adresse: 127.0.0.1
Port: 55098
---------
7
```

If someone can help to figure my errors out. Thanks :)

Comment: There's no error. Look up the term "ephemeral port"

Comment: Ok but how it can explain that sometimes the port is negative and that the client address changed?

Comment: It can't go negative. It's an unsigned short. 0-65535. You're not printing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this point from the `accept(2)` manpage:

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must
>          initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed
>          to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer
>          address.

This means, that you have to do

```
socklen_t size = sizeof client_addr;
```

Otherwise the returned address is truncated if the value in `size` (which is indeterminate) is too small, which means, that the contents may remain uninitialized (completely or partially). This leads to the strange values you observe.

Another issue is, that the `bind()` may fail with *Address already in use* when the port was recently used (TIME_WAIT state). In this case, the port is bound automatically from a certain, implementation defined range. To avoid this, you can set the option `SO_REUSEADDR` before the `bind()`:

```
int one = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));
```

Furthermore, it is very advisable to check all return values for errors; you would have noticed `bind()` failing then.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i didn't notice. But is there anyway to fix the port number to be always the same as the one passed in argument?

Comment: @ZyxcelZoïd I have added an explanation why sometimes another port may have been boudn